# Liste des mots contenant « à »

Tags: orthographe, diacritiques, alphabet, lexique

Quelle est la liste de tous les mots français contenant la lettre « à » ?

Exemples: *à*, *çà*, *là*, *déjà*, *voilà*, *au-delà*.

Answer (score 4):

Voici les mots simples et les pronoms composés courants :

> à
>   au-delà
>   çà
>   celle-là
>   celles-là
>   celui-là
>   ceux-là
>   delà
>   deçà
>   déjà
>   holà
>   jusque-là
>   là
>   là-bas
>   là-dessous
>   là-dessus
>   là-haut
>   par-delà
>   par-là
>   pietà
>   revoilà
>   voilà

Et les mots composés qui contiennent la préposition *à* :

> à-coup
>   à-côté
>   à-peu-près
>   à-pic
>   à-propos
>   à-valoir
>   à-venir
>   bouche-à-bouche
>   bric-à-brac
>   c'est-à-dire
>   face-à-face
>   face-à-main
>   fier-à-bras
>   garde-à-vous
>   goutte-à-goutte
>   pied-à-terre
>   porte-à-faux
>   porte-à-porte
>   propre-à-rien
>   prêt-à-porter
>   quant-à-soi
>   touche-à-tout
>   tête-à-queue
>   tête-à-tête
>   vis-à-vis

Answer (score 2):

En excluant les mots composés, en voilà quelques uns:

- à
- çà
- deçà
- déjà
- delà
- holà
- houlà
- jà
- là
- pietà
- revoilà
- voilà